# Change order of infima over of uncountable sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Is it true that for uncountable sets $A,B$ and real valued function $f(\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;)$?

$$\inf_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B} f(a,b)=\inf_{(a,b)\in A\times B} f(a,b) = \inf_{b\in B}\inf_{a\in A} f(a,b).\label{result1}$$
I understand from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99440/switching-order-of-supremum-for-doubly-indexed-sequence) that it is true when both $A,B$ are countably infinite.

How does one deal with if both are uncountable?

This is how much I could proceed:
Using
$$\inf_{b'\in B} f(a,b') \leq f(a,b)$$
one can obtain

$$\inf_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B} f(a,b)\leq \inf_{(a,b)\in A\times B} f(a,b)$$

Now I have to prove the opposite of this inequality, and I am stuck at this step.

Can someone point to how this can be done or is it that in general the result is false for uncountable sets?

Comment: Have you tried reading the accepted answer to the question you linked?  Nothing in it requires the index sets to be countable...

Comment: @EricWofsey you are right! thanks! I did not notice this!